# Symmetric Simple Random Walk paths

Tags: probability, random-walk

How many random walk paths of length 10 reach 5 (or higher), but end at 4 or lower?

I know that the number of paths with $_{10}$ > 4 is equal to the number of paths with $_{10}$ < 4, but I am struggling to incorporate the maximum of $_{10}$ >= 5. I understand that the reflection principle is a key component of this question, but I am having trouble implementing this idea.

How would this question be applied to other problems such as "How many random walk paths of length 10 reach 5 (or higher), and end at 3 or lower?"

I am trying to conceptually understand the idea, so if anyone would be willing to explain, that would be great! Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "I know that the number of paths with $X_{10} > 4$ is equal to the number of paths with $X_{10} < 4$" 
Is this really so? Is it a combinatorial fact special for $4$ and $10$? (of course it's not true for general values)

Comment: I thought the reflection principle stated the number of paths with $X_{10}$ > 4  is equal to the number of paths with $X_{10}$ < 4? Am I understanding the principle incorrectly?

Comment: Is this a one-dimensional random walk?  Does is have any barriers?

Comment: Yes, one-dimensional and no barriers. We have not learned of barriers or multi dimensional random walks